Max retries exceeded error while using python's geopy.geocoders.Nominatim
I used kivy to build an android app and buildozer to transport it to my phone as an apk file.
When I run the python code on my computer regularly geopy.geocoders.Nominatim works completely fine, but when I run the app on my phone, I get the error:

geopy.exc.GeocoderUnavailable:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): Max
retries exceeded with url: /reverse?lat=[I censored the
location]&lon=[I censored the location]format=json&addressdetails=1
(Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL:
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get
local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)')))

Does anyobody know how to solve this problem?
I dont really know what to try since I've never used geopy before.

this is probably related with a firewall. Try running on a different computer. @big_shlomi
